# Make a Stub for nesting function in Yii2

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, codeception, stub

I learn to use Unit test in Yii2 with Codeception, and try to check if a billing is a "daily" billing from a merchant's setting.

```
$this->biller->merchant->detail->rule_type == self::PERIODIC_MODE_DAILY
```

I don't know how to mock that `rule_type` value if I use a `Stub::make()` function.

What I tried so far is using the nested array like this (doesn't work) :

```
$billing = Stub::make(Billing::class, [
    'status'        => Billing::STATUS_ACTIVE,
    'set_periodic_by' => Billing::SET_PERIODIC_BY_MERCHANT,
    'biller' => [
        'merchant' => [
            'detail' => [
                'rule_type' => Billing::PERIODIC_MODE_DAILY,
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

And I also tried to mock each of the object model using another Stub::make()

```
$billing = Stub::make(Billing::class, [
    'status'        => Billing::STATUS_ACTIVE,
    'set_periodic_by' => Billing::SET_PERIODIC_BY_MERCHANT,
    'getBiller' => Stub::make(Biller::class, [
        'getMerchant' => Stub::make(Merchant::class, [
            'getDetail' => Stub::make(MerchantDetail::class, [
                'rule_type' => Billing::PERIODIC_MODE_DAILY,
            ])
        ])
    ])
]);
```

How do I properly create a "nested" function return values using Stub? Any comment or answer is always welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Casting the nested array to `(object)` will do

```
$billing = Stub::make(Billing::class, [
    'status'                => Billing::STATUS_ACTIVE,
    'set_periodic_by'       => Billing::SET_PERIODIC_BY_MERCHANT,
    'getBiller'             => (object) [
        'merchant'          => (object) [
            'detail'        => (object) [
                'rule_type' => Billing::PERIODIC_MODE_DAILY,
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```